# Looking for a physics textbook on fluid mechanics

Tags: fluid-dynamics, resource-recommendations, education

The title pretty much explains itself, could someone recommend me a textbook on fluid mechanics for someome who knows nothing about it? I've already learnt some vector calculus and I'd like to learn fluid mechanics so I can use them.